# How did the Hive achieve space travel?

Tags: destiny-2

As we've seen across the Destiny franchise the Hive have used ships to travel across the galaxy and also to deploy troops to the surface of worlds.

As a seemingly unintelligent species, how have the Hive achieved space travel?

Comment: they are technically an ancient race. They may seem unintelligent, but they have been around making a mess of things for a very long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the Hive that is encountered on a daily basis appear to have below average intelligence, they consistent of supreme and highly intelligent beings - like Oryx and the Worm Gods.

Oryx mentions how the Hive obtained the ability to travel through space in his [Books of Sorrow](https://www.ishtar-collective.net/categories/books-of-sorrow). Using knowledge from a world they conquered, the Hive are able to cut holes in space itself to create openings that allows them to travel anywhere they desire in an instant.

> Xivu Arath, knight morph of Xi Ro. You love to conquer, don’t you? We love to see you work. Nearly two percent of Fundament’s surface is now our dominion. Your species embraces the worm.
>
> The syzygy has passed. The God-Wave will reach you in less than two years.
>
> Our organs informs us that Taox and her surviving Refusalists flee towards Kaharn Atoll. >She hopes to rally the species of Fundament against you. The Leviathan’s agents work tirelessly to destroy ships and engines, trapping us on Fundament.
>
> If we cannot make ships, we will become them.
>
> **Overwhelm the Kaharn bastion. Slaughter everyone there. From your acts we shall obtain the logic we require to cut space open and migrate to orbit.**
>
> Reality is a fine flesh, oh general ours. Let us feast of it.
>
> <sub>[Verse 2:2. Out of the Deep](https://www.ishtar-collective.net/cards/xii-out-of-the-deep#books-of-sorrow)</sub>